# how to programmatically post blog to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for API which i can use to programmatically post blogs on wordpress.
Please note that I want to redirect user to wordpress and hence I am looking for a "GET" wordpress API.

Comment: Are you saying that HTTP POSTs are not viable?  If you did redirect to wordpress, how are normal redirects not meeting that need?  I'm a bit confused about what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the wordpress function [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

```
// Create post object
  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'My post',
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_author' => 1,
     'post_category' => array(8,39)
  );

// Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: is there any way to submit parameters as "GET" request ?

Comment: When I use this function the posts are created, but as soon as I view them on the front-end they are moved to the trash. I try to restore them but it just keeps happening. The status is publish, the category ID is correct. Anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress support both the Atom Publishing Protocol and XML-RPC.  The simplist solution might be to use the post-by-email feature.  Your program can send blog entries via email.

Comment: can you point me to some examples for using Atom Publishing Protocol and XML-RPC and  how to use it in code ?

Comment: I haven't needed to do this yet, but here is a good starting point (written by Eric Kidd): http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XML-RPC-HOWTO/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WordPress XML-RPC Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) which shows you how you can use different APIs such as the Blogger API, metaWeblog API, and the Movable Type API in your client.

Comment: I was referring to press-this.php api .. Can you point me to some examples ?